# Django-storage - How to check file size prior to upload?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models

Storage and Django 1.6:

I want to restrict filesizes saved to `s3`. What is the appropriate way to do this?
Should I just do custom field validation in the form or is there a better way to do this when using Django-Storage?

Comment: After reading @NorbertSebők's  answer I also added JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 2):

Validation requires the file to be uploaded to the server. The [suggested way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#user-uploaded-content) is to set the limit in your web server config. A better solution is [to check the file size in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.size) *before* uploading:

```
// fileInput is a HTMLInputElement: 
<input type="file" multiple id="myfileinput">
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");

// files is a FileList object (simliar to NodeList)
var files = fileInput.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  alert(files[i].name + " has a size of " + files[i].size + " Bytes");
}
```

Comment: if i'm using django-storages to save to s3, i'm assuming that web server config will do nothing correct?

Comment: @w, the web server will return an error response (413) instead of servicing the request. The Django code will not even notice that there was a failed request. So setting LimitRequestBody is a good idea for enhancing security but a JS check is a more user friendly solution.