# Validating Upload file in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Here I,m using Django-REST framework for file upload, I'm not using a model layer in Django. So I am using default_storage for the uploaded file to save. My question here is how would I  validate the files. Uploaded file should not exixts 10mb.Thanks in Advance.

```
class imageapi(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
            try:

                form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                #save_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads', request.FILES['file'])

                save_path = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)+ '/uploads/'+str(request.FILES['file'])
                path = default_storage.save(str(save_path), request.FILES['file'])
                return Response({default_storage.path(path)})
            except Exception as ex:
                return Response({"DATA": str(ex)})
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. The django way:**

You can check the size of the file in your form like this: `field_name.size`. This will return the size in bytes.

**2. The server way:**

You can configure your frontend server (Nginx, or Apacher, or whatever you're using) not to accept files more than 10 mb. This approach is better and safer.

Comment: thanks @xyres .. will you share some code in python to validate

Comment: @selvakumar check docs on field validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Multiple answers here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21201525/5177450) and the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#user-uploaded-content) suggest handling this on your webserver.

If using nginx, you can limit the filesize by using the `client_max_body_size` in the http block:

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```